# How to install the GDAL plugin for QGIS 2.0 on Linux Mint?

Tags: qgis, gdal, linux-mint

What do I need to access the GDAL plugin in QGIS 2.0?

I've installed QGIS on my Linux Mint 16 64bit system, but can't access the GDAL Contour tool.

The problem seems to lie with my package dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gdal
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... 
Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libgsl0ldbl libqwt5-qt4 libspatialindex1 libspatialite3 libxerces-c28
qgis-common qgis-providers-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
libgdal1h libkml0 libspatialite5 liburiparser1
Recommended packages:
proj-bin
The following packages will be REMOVED
libgdal1 libqgis2.0.1 qgis qgis-providers qlandkartegt
The following NEW packages will be installed
libgdal1h libkml0 libspatialite5 liburiparser1 python-gdal
```

Obviously I don't want QGIS uninstalled, but how can I access the GDAL plugins without python-gdal?

I'm sure this is a simple oversight but it's been driving me just a little bit crazy!

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? I've been using Mint with everything working fine...

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to uninstall Qgis and after  to do a fresh installation from [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable), all dependencies (gdal,proj4, geos, etc) will be automatically satisfied.

I use Linux Mint 13 "Maya", so for me Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) works fine.
For you I think it will be Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy).